# C# WPF - Get the selected items from a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a listview with multiple columns. The data are binding with a DataView. The first column is the ID, the second column is the name.

When one item is selected on my listview named lstInterrogateur, i get the ID like that:

```
DataRowView CompRow;
string InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO interrogateur_matiere (idinterrogateur_matiere, idMatiere, idInterrogateur) VALUES ";
int SComp, i=1, total;
long idInterrogateur, idMatiere;

SComp = lstInterrogateur.SelectedIndex;
CompRow = lstInterrogateur.Items.GetItemAt(SComp) as DataRowView;
idInterrogateur = Convert.ToInt16(CompRow["idInterrogateur"]);
```

And when multiple items are selected on my listview named lstMatiereInterrogateur, i get the ID like that:

```
total = lstMatiereInterrogateur.SelectedItems.Count;

foreach (var item in lstMatiereInterrogateur.SelectedItems)
{                    
   SComp = lstMatiereInterrogateur.SelectedIndex;
   CompRow = lstMatiereInterrogateur.Items.GetItemAt(SComp) as DataRowView;
   idMatiere = Convert.ToInt16(CompRow["idMatiere"]);
   InsertQuery += "(NULL, '" + idInterrogateur + "', '" + idMatiere + "')";
   if (total != i)
       InsertQuery += ", ";
       i++;
   }
}
```

But then i only get the last ID. For exemple, i selected 2 items ID=3 et ID=5, i will get 2 times ID=5. Why?

Thanks.

Comment: check the `SelectionMode` Property

Comment: SelectionMode is set on Multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `SelectedIndex` to get each item in the loop over `SelectedItems`. Instead, access them by the loop variable:

```
foreach (var item in lstMatiereInterrogateur.SelectedItems)
{                    
    CompRow = item as DataRowView;
    idMatiere = Convert.ToInt16(CompRow["idMatiere"]);
    ...
}
```

---

Similarly you could use `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedIndex` to access a single selected item:

```
CompRow = lstInterrogateur.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
idInterrogateur = Convert.ToInt16(CompRow["idInterrogateur"]);
```