# WPF C# loop through ListView selected items

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I have a listview and will need to loop through the selected item collection. But I am getting an error below is my code:

```
 DataRowView drv;
 foreach(var current in lstValue.SelectedItems)
 {
        ListBoxItem li  = new ListBoxItem();
        drv = current as DataRowView;
        li.Content = Criteria + "=" + drv["CODE"];
        lstSelection.Items.Add(li);
 }
```

I get the error object reference not set to the instance of an object. This is the stack over flow link I already looked  up

[C# WPF - Get the selected items from a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901042/c-sharp-wpf-get-the-selected-items-from-a-listview)

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: my datarowview is null . drv is not getting filled. am I doing it right??

Comment: Its just a multicolumn item with CODE and DESCRIPTION. It ideally should iterate through the selected items and get me all the  CODE's

Comment: As Blam said, which line throws the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should check:

```
if( lstValue != null)
{
    foreach(var current in lstValue.SelectedItems)
    {
      // Your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRowView drv;
foreach(var current in lstValue.SelectedItems)
{
    ListBoxItem li  = new ListBoxItem();
    drv = current as DataRowView;
    if (drv != null)
    {
        li.Content = Criteria + "=" + drv["CODE"];
        lstSelection.Items.Add(li);
    }
}
```

Comment: My DataRowView is not getting filled up its not null